# Questions on Griffon getting started?

Tags: griffon, lazybones

I install the lazybones successfully no I am on the next instruction below.

```
Next register the griffon-lazybones-templates repository with         
Lazybones' config file. Edit $USER_HOME/.lazybones/config.groovy
```

But I cannot find .lazybones directory in my home directory? Where did they put the it. Where or how do I find it?

Answer (score 0):

What's your environment? Could it be you're using Windows? If so please follow the instructions found in Tutorial 1 http://griffon-framework.org/tutorials/1_getting_started.html

Comment: I am using it in ubuntu and facing the same issues.
could you please guide us?

Comment: AFAIK `$USER_HOME/.lazybones` should have been created automatically the first time you invoke the  `lazybones` command. However you can always create that directory and the `config.groovy` file manually.